# How make a Discord Embed Message Template for GitLab

Tags: discord, gitlab

I'm creating a personal Discord server and in between crazy setups I wanted to do, I stumbled upon webhooks. For my work, I use GitLab, so I created a personal project, a notification channel and a WebHook in this channel (which I already linked to GitLab). Now, I wanted to start testing notifications (starting with Merge Request), but there is a default message that GitLab offers.

> It is necessary to mention that in the same notifications section, it requests another WebHook URL to overwrite the default message.

This is all I have done:

[image]

Has anyone perhaps in the community already managed to have custom messages brought directly from GitLab, or GitHub?

Please, I know that it's possible! But I can't found information.

Comment: But I don't have any code. I haven't really done any of that, just creating and connecting the WebHooks.

Answer (score 1):

We managed to do it but cheated a bit.

One of our jobs execute a curl on the webhook URL from our CI

You need to send this json:

```
{
  "embeds": [
    {
      "title": "$TITLE",
      "author": {
        "name": "Triggered by $GITLAB_USER_NAME"
      },
      "description": "$DESCRIPTION",
      "color": "$COLOR"
    }
  ]
}
```

Like this:

```
curl \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data "$thejson" \
  "$WEBHOOK_URL"
```

It doesn't directly use the gitlab embedded githook but it did the job for us.